# Why my displacement node is moving my Meshes/displacement's meshes when rendering an animation?

Tags: displacement

I'm making an animation of a Planet that I've made. There is 3 spheres: Planet, Clouds and Atmosphere. I added a displacement node to the Planet and the Clouds but when rendering, my Planet looks like it's moving away from its position the same for the Clouds. [image]

[image]

[image]

I deactivated the Clouds displacement node but still left the planet one and we can see that on that frame (206),on the viewport, the Planet is far from the ship but got closer when rendered even though I didn't add any keyframes or whatsoever on the displacement node and that the midlevel is at 0,5.

FYI, I manually subdivide in Edit mode x25 and added a subdivision modifier with a level 2 in Render on every sphere.

Does anyone have any clue of what happened?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EEVEE, or if the displacement setting for the material is “bump only”, the Displacement node and material output only affects the normals of the mesh. Various angles will produce/reveal “impossible” lighting reflections. In this case, the planet really isn’t moving, you’re just seeing through the illusion at some points and not at others.

In the case of Cycles, go to Properties editor -> Material Properties tab -> Settings panel, and change the displacement setting to “displacement only” or “displacement and bump.”

In the case of EEVEE, discard the Displacement node and use a displacement modifier instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I'm using Cycles and switch to Displacement and Bump before rendering, that's why I was confused